# I tried to disable the button after the first click.it's working for me now. when the dialog box closed i want the button enabled again

Tags: button, visual-c++, mfc

```
void CMyViewerDlg::OnBnClickedShow()
{

    m_DCM.Create(IDD_TAG, this);
    m_DCM.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
    BOOL isOn = true;
    if (isOn == false)
    {
        GetDlgItem(IDC_SHOW)->EnableWindow(TRUE);
    }

    else
    {
        GetDlgItem(IDC_SHOW)->EnableWindow(FALSE);
    }
 }
```

now the button is disabled after the first click..i want to enable the button again when i close the dialog box..help me to slove this problem..

Comment: Handle this in OnCancel() and OnOK().

Comment: @ThomasWoelfer This is a non modal dialog...

Answer (score 0):

This is a non **modeless** dialog. So you have to keep track of it on your own. The easiest way would be to send a `WM_APP+n` message to the parent window/dialog, when the dialog receives the `OnDestroy` or `OnClose` event. The parent dialog can handle this message and disable the appropriate button.

Another method is just setting a timer. In the timer you can check if `m_DCMTagDlg.m_hWnd` is still not `NULL`. If it reaches `NULL` just disable the button.

Comment: could you please show me how to do this with WM_APP+n

Comment: #define WM_MYSPECIALMSG (WM_APP+4711)

Answer (score 0):

This is not meant to replace the existing answer but it is based on the comments.

[image: Using Classwizard]

You can use the **Classwizard** to add custom message handlers. I create a GUID and attach that to `WM_APP` and use **registered** messages.